# Structure of Ruby code which is not intended to be a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sdk

I'm working on a specific project where I have to write a SDK (kind of gem) on top of openid_connect gem. Currently my code consists of single file (but I'm also going to write some tests for it) and sample app which shows the use of SDK. Problem is that I cannot ship SDK as a rubygem as it has to be pushed to the same git repository as sample app. Client is going to use only SDK. SDK is a single class with methods in it.

My current approach is to write SDK in RubyOnRails /lib folder (but SDK has to work with other ruby frameworks as well) and let client download the SDK located inside sample app's lib folder.

1)Should my code go inside lib or vendor directory? Or there is some better approach?

2)How this code can be included in ruby app? Installed as a gem or included by require...

3)Can the tests go in the same folder as SDK (not in rails /test folder)?

Comment: I would write a gem (including tests) and put the sample app in its own git repository, along with a Gemfile that includes the gem.

Comment: Yes but the specific requirement of the project is to push both sample app and gem to the same git repo.

Comment: Your gem could have an `examples` directory that includes the sample app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It sounds like this code is not at all dependent on Rails.  As such, do not create a Rails project for it.  That would be adding ceremony and dependency that are unnecessary.

2) There is nothing wrong with having sample files in a gem's git repo.  You can put them in a directory named `samples` or `examples`, for example.

3) To create a conventional gem directory structure, use `bundle`:

```
bundle gem my_gem_name
```

4) Your tests should go in a directory named `test` if they are Minitest, or `spec` if they are RSpec.